# Как отформатировать время в соответствии с системными установками

Tags: java, android, дата, время

В андроиде может быть установлен 12 или 24-часовой формат для времени. Как узнать эту настройку, чтобы создать SimpleDateFormat соответственно с "HH:mm" или "hh:mm aa"? Или какой другой способ показать время в том формате, как оно задано в системе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
boolean is24HourFormat = dateFormat.is24HourFormat(mContext);
```